¿Como nombrar un repositorio python?
En python he notado que una vez haces git clone a un repositorio de github, el proyecto no se deja llamar si el nombre de su directorio tiene guiones.
¿Se considera mala práctica nombrar un repositorio de python en github con guiones en su nombre?
Profesionalmente ¿Cómo es recomendable hacerlo?
Caso de Apple:

Vemos que en Apple prácticamente todos sus repositorios de python usan guiones y que sus nombres corresponden a un contexto que pueden relacionar los repositorios entre si, de ahí el uso de guiones.
Generalmente los Bancos también trabajan de esta forma, aunque a python no le guste a la hora de nombrar directorios, que contendrán ficheros de python que deban ser llamados desde afuera. No lo permite.

Yo creo que no. Te doy un ejemplo: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot (aunque se importa como telegram).

Python no permite usar "-" en los identificadores por razones obvias, no obstante una cosa es el nombre de distribución de un paquete y otra su nombre de importación como muy bien muestra el ejemplo de Mateo. El primero debe ser único si se quiere publicar en PyPi, el segundo no aunque es recomendable para evitar conflictos entre paquetes.

Es decir, puedes llamar a tu proyecto como quieras en GitHub y el nombre de distribución del paquete (que puede también variar del del proyecto y configurarse con setuptools) puede contener "-" sin problemas. Lo que no puedes hacer es usar "-" para nombrar un paquete/módulo/clase/función/variable en el paquete una vez instalado, porque obviamente "-" es el operador de sustracción y no puedes usarlo en el nombre de un identificador y por tanto no puedes hacer import un-paquete.

Muchas gracias por sus aportes.

@oscargonzalez la pregunta es muy amplia y da pie a opiniones, pero si tienes alguna duda concreta del proceso no dudes en preguntar. Como comentamos nombrar así los proyectos es una practica relativamente común, si te das una vuelta por PyPi hay bastantes de ellos. Si te vas a sus repos puedes mirarte sus setup.py y scripts de construcción/instalación para ver como manejan lo de los nombres y que es realmente lo que se termina instalando con pip.

Mi opinión personal es que se puede nombrar como se quiera el repo, pero el paquete en PyPi y su forma de importar considero que es mejor que coincidan y sean únicas en lo posible, evitando conflictos con otros paquetes y por supuesto la stdlib, esto evita errores y más de una pregunta aquí por importar o instalar el paquete equivocado... Los usuarios tienden (con razón) a pensar que si un paquete se llama foo en PyPi se importe luego con import foo y al contrario. Hay casos donde no hacer esto esta justificado y se hace por una razón muy concreta, como pillow/PIL. Saludos.
